Не устанавливается «Inference»
При выполнении вывода установки (pip install inference) возникает ошибка.
import distutils.core ModuleNotFoundError: нет модуля с именем «distutils».
Что я делаю не так?
Обнаружение объектов
Windows/Google Chrome
Screws2 Набор данных изображений


Вы пробовали установить модуль distultils?

Во-первых, Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?. Во-вторых, по косвенным данным я предполагаю, что у вас Python 3.12, и похоже этот inference под эту версию Python не обновлен. Пробуйте установить setuptools (куда входит distutils, и который был в 3.12 выпилен из стандартной библиотеки Python) отдельно, но это не гарантирует работоспособность. Либо используйте Python 3.11.

Да, в данном случае важно указать версию питона в тегах. В свежих версиях что-то поменялось с distutils, да.

insolor, я учту ваши пожелания насчет картинок. Большое спасибо!!! "Либо используйте Python 3.11" - а как это сделать? Я пока только учусь...

Почитайте про окружения питона. У вас может быть много разных версий питона на одном компьютере. В любом случае вам нужно будет разобраться, как работать с окружениями.

"я учту ваши пожелания насчет картинок." - это не мои пожелания, это де-факто правило. К тому же, неужели проще было сделать этот длинный скриншот, чем просто вставить текст? 4881px в высоту, серьезно? Как вы вообще это сделали, у вас настолько большой монитор или вы скриншотили и вручную склеивали фрагменты?

"Либо используйте Python 3.11" - а как это сделать?" - проще всего удалить установленный Python, скачать с официального сайта Python 3.11 и установить его.

Нет, я не склеивала))) Я для скриншотов использую "FastStoneCapture", там есть кнопка "Захват окна с прокруткой". Я использовала ее)

Все работает! Спасибо огромное!!!
